# How do you show a user that their 3 digit integer input has the same numbers as a computer generated 3 digit integer but they're in a wrong position?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am creating a guessing game where you need to guess the exact number that the computer (i.e Python) has generated. I am making it have an easy mode (which generates a 3-digit number for the user to guess) and a hard mode (which generates a 4-digit number for the user to guess).

However, for the easy mode, I want to be able to tell the user that they have one (or more) number in their guess which is correct but it is in the wrong position.

So far, I have used index positions for the computer to note what numbers (in what order) are in the computer-generated, as shown in my code below:

```
def easy_mode(): 
    easy_num = randint(100,999)
    easy_digit_splitter1 = str(easy_num)[0]
    easy_digit_splitter2 = str(easy_num)[1]
    easy_digit_splitter3 = str(easy_num)[2]
```

I know that I will need a variable that stores the user's guess under the code above (as well as a while loop), but how do I  compare both the "easy_num" and the variable which will store the user's guess and tell the user that they have a correct number in their guess but it's in the wrong position?

Answer (score 0):

Once you get your user guess and your random number you can convert to list and iterate:

```
easy_num_list = list(str(easy_num))
user_guess_list = list(user_guess)
#iterate through each digit in the user guess. `i` is the index of the digit we are iterating. 
for i in range(0, len(user_guess_list)):
```

Then in that loop you can do your testing:

```
easy_num_list = list(str(easy_num))
user_guess_list = list(user_guess)
#iterate through each digit in the user guess. `i` is the index of the digit we are iterating. 
for i in range(0, len(user_guess_list)):
    #use the `in` operator to see if this digit from the user's guess is in the randomly generated number
    if user_guess_list[i] in easy_num_list:
        print("number",user_guess_list[i],"is in the random number")
        #check to see if this digit from the user's guess is in the exact same index/position as the randomly generated number
        if user_guess_list[i] == easy_num_list[i]:
            print("and it's in the right spot")
        else:
            print("but it's not in the right spot")
    else:
        print("number",user_guess_list[i],"is not in the random number")
```

There's more clean and elegant ways to do this logic, but this should get you in the ballpark.

Comment: Thank you for this! Let me try and see if it works!